# Jboss, use enterprise bean in security interceptor

Tags: hibernate, jboss, ejb, resteasy, interceptor

I'm new to J2EE and I have a jboss implementation of a Rest-Based web service. I'm not very familiar with all the frameworks and so on in jboss.  For security I have implemented a SecurityInterceptor where i get a NullPointerException.
The problem is the kryptoManager.getKryptoInformation(); call because kryptoManager is null.

```
@EJB
KryptoManager kryptoManager;

@Override
public boolean accept(Class c, Method method) {
    if (c == null || method == null) return false;
    //class implementing rest service
    return method.getName().equals("restService");

}

@Override
public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method)
        throws Failure, WebApplicationException {
    ServerResponse response = null;

    String key = kryptoManager.getKryptoInformation();

    ...

    if (error) {
        response = new ServerResponse(LOGINURL, 403, new Headers<Object>());
    }


    return response;
}
```

I have also a Servlet and the restService running, where I can access the kryptoManager by the getKryptoInformation method. (There I don't have to create some Instances or whatever)
Why can't the interceptor also access the database over the KryptoBean ? Is there another possibility to access or get my information from the database in the backend.
The KryptoManager looks like:

```
@Stateless
public class KryptoManager {

    @EJB
    private KryptoDAO kryptoDAO;

    public KryptoBean getKryptoInformation() {
        return kryptoDAO.getKryptoInformation();
    }

}
```

The KryptoDAO looks like:

```
@Stateless
public class KryptoDAO {

     @PersistenceContext(unitName = "db", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
     private EntityManager entityManager;


     public KryptoBean getKryptoInformation() {
         Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT k FROM KryptoBean k");
         return (KryptoBean) query.getResultList().get(0);

     }
}
```

And the Bean Class looks like:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "krypto")
@Entity(name = "KryptoBean")
public class KryptoBean {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idkrypto")
    private int idkrypto;

    @Column (name = "hmackey")
    private String hmackey;

    public int getIdkrypto() {
        return idkrypto;
    }

    public void setIdkrypto(int idkrypto) {
        this.idkrypto = idkrypto;
    }

    public String getHmackey() {
        return hmackey;
    }

    public void setHmackey(String hmackey) {
        this.hmackey = hmackey;
    }

}
```

And the JaxRsActivator looks like:

```
@ApplicationPath( "/rest" )
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application
{

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getClasses();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getSingletons();
    }

}
```